# CROSS APPLY Creating Additional Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, cross-apply

I am trying to create a report that display potential duplicate records based on three criteria: the last 4 of an SSN, last name and DOB.  I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083654/separate-potential-duplicates-into-different-rows) on the issue and received an answer that I should be using a Cross Apply to unpivot the data. The query runs fast and the results look better than my original query.

The new query is below and I have added a filter to show two examples that I am seeing occur across the data:

```
DECLARE
@StartDate DATE = '1/1/2017',
@EndDate DATE = '3/1/2017';

WITH
CTE
AS
(
SELECT  
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c.socialSecurityNumber) AS [SSNRanking] ,

    c.id AS [CustomerID]  ,
    c.socialSecurityNumber AS [SSN],         
    c.firstName AS [FirstName] ,    
    c.lastName AS [LastName] ,
    c.birthDate [BirthDate] ,
    c.emailAddress AS [EmailAddress],
    c.createDate AS [CreateDate] ,
    MAX(co.orderDate) AS [LastOrderDate] ,
    ca.street1 AS [Addr1] ,
    ca.city AS [City] ,
    ca.stateAndTerritoriesID AS [State],
    ca.zipCode5 AS [Zip] ,

    c2.id AS [DupCustomerID] ,
    c2.socialSecurityNumber AS [DupSSN] ,        
    c2.firstName AS [DupFirstName] ,
    c2.lastName AS [DupLastName] ,
    c2.birthDate AS [DupBirthDate] ,
    c2.emailAddress AS [DupEmailAddress] ,
    c2.createDate AS [DupCreateDate] ,
    MAX(co.orderDate) AS [DupLastOrderDate] ,
    ca.street1 AS [DupAddr1] ,
    ca.city AS [DupCity],
    ca.stateAndTerritoriesID AS [DupState] ,
    ca.zipCode5 AS [DupZip]

FROM    
    dbo.Customers AS [c]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customers AS [c2] ON ( SUBSTRING(c.socialSecurityNumber,6,4) = SUBSTRING(c2.socialSecurityNumber,6,4) AND c.birthDate = c2.birthDate AND c.lastName = c2.lastName AND c.id <> c2.id )
    INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerAddresses AS [ca] ON c.id = ca.customerID
    --INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerAddresses AS [ca2] ON ca2.customerID = c2.id        
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Common_Orders AS [co] ON co.customerID = c.id
WHERE
    c.customerStatusTypeID <> 'M'
    AND c2.customerStatusTypeID <> 'M'
    AND ca.addressType = 'M'
    --AND ca2.addressType = 'M'
    AND c.mergedTo IS NULL
    AND c2.mergedTo IS NULL
    AND CAST(co.orderDate AS DATE) >= @StartDate
    AND CAST(co.orderDate AS DATE) <= @EndDate
    AND ( c.id = 1545229 OR c.id = 2020489 )
GROUP BY
    c.id ,
    c.socialSecurityNumber ,        
    c.firstName ,
    c.lastName ,
    c.birthDate ,
    c.emailAddress ,      
    c.createDate ,
    ca.street1 ,
    ca.city ,
    ca.stateAndTerritoriesID ,
    ca.zipCode5 ,

    c2.id ,
    c2.socialSecurityNumber ,        
    c2.firstName ,        
    c2.lastName ,
    c2.birthDate ,
    c2.emailAddress ,
    c2.createDate ,
    ca.street1 ,
    ca.city ,
    ca.stateAndTerritoriesID ,
    ca.zipCode5
)
SELECT CA.CustomerID,
CA.SSNRanking ,  
CA.SSN ,    
CA.FirstName,
CA.LastName,
CA.BirthDate,
CA.EmailAddress,
CA.CreateDate ,
CA.LastOrderDate ,
CA.Addr1,
CA.City,
CA.[State],
CA.Zip
FROM
CTE
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES
    (CTE.SSNRanking, CTE.CustomerID,    CTE.SSN,     CTE.FirstName,    CTE.LastName,    CTE.Birthdate,    CTE.EmailAddress,    CTE.CreateDate,    CTE.LastOrderDate,    CTE.Addr1,    CTE.City,    CTE.[State],  CTE.Zip),
    (CTE.SSNRanking, CTE.DupCustomerID, CTE.DupSSN,  CTE.DupFirstName, CTE.DuplastName, CTE.DupBirthDate, CTE.DupEmailAddress, CTE.DupCreateDate, CTE.DupLastOrderDate, CTE.DupAddr1, CTE.DupCity, CTE.DupState, CTE.DupZip)
) AS CA (SSNRanking, CustomerID, SSN, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, EmailAddress, CreateDate, LastOrderDate, Addr1, City, [State], Zip)
ORDER BY CAST(CA.SSN AS INT) ASC, CA.CustomerID;
```

And the result set looks like ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3E2E.png)):

```
+ ---------- + ---------- + --------- + ---------- + -------- + ---------- + ------------ + --------------------- + ----------------------- + --------------------- + ------------ + ----- + ----- +
| CustomerId | SSNRanking | SSN       | FirstName  | LastName | BirthDate  | EmailAddress | CreateDate            | LastOrderDate           | Addr1                 | City         | State | Zip   |
+ ---------- + ---------- + --------- + ---------- + -------- + ---------- + ------------ + --------------------- + ----------------------- + --------------------- + ------------ + ----- + ----- +
| 1545229    | 1          | 000000000 | Aquia Boat | SALES    | 1900-01-01 | null         | 2013-05-28 00:00:00.0 | 2017-01-23 11:08:30.723 | 236 Willow Landing Rd | Stafford     | VA    | 22554 |
| 1545229    | 1          | 000000000 | Aquia Boat | SALES    | 1900-01-01 | null         | 2013-05-28 00:00:00.0 | 2017-01-06 12:31:15.370 | 11963 Jefferson Ave   | Newport News | VA    | 23606 |
| 2020489    | 1          | 000000000 | DIXIE      | SALES    | 1900-01-01 | null         | 2017-01-06 12:27:56.5 | 2017-01-06 12:31:15.370 | 11963 Jefferson Ave   | Newport News | VA    | 23606 |
| 2020489    | 1          | 000000000 | DIXIE      | SALES    | 1900-01-01 | null         | 2017-01-06 12:27:56.5 | 2017-01-23 11:08:30.723 | 236 Willow Landing Rd | Stafford     | VA    | 22554 |
+ ---------- + ---------- + --------- + ---------- + -------- + ---------- + ------------ + --------------------- + ----------------------- + --------------------- + ------------ + ----- + ----- +
```

And I see that the last four of the SSN, last name and DOB all match.  But then I noticed duplicate Customer IDs Aqua Boats has an entry with the Dixie Sales address and Dixie Sales has an entry for Aqua Boats address - which I should not have and I looked in the Customer /Customer Addresses table at the particular accounts:

```
SELECT c.id, c.socialSecurityNumber, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.birthDate, ca.street1
    FROM dbo.Customers AS c
    INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerAddresses AS [ca] ON ca.customerID = c.id
    WHERE c.id IN (1545229,2020489) AND ca.addressType = 'M';
```

And the results are here ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaVYP.png)):

```
+ ---------- + -------------------- + ---------- + -------- + ---------- + --------------------- +
| id         | socialSecurityNumber | firstName  | lastName | birthDate  | street 1              |
+ ---------- + -------------------- + ---------- + -------- + ---------- + --------------------- +
| 1545229    | 000000000            | Aquia Boat | SALES    | 1900-01-01 | 236 Willow Landing Rd |
| 2020489    | 000000000            | DIXIE      | SALES    | 1900-01-01 | 11963 Jefferson Ave   |
+ ---------- + -------------------- + ---------- + -------- + ---------- + --------------------- +
```

When I run the query inside the CTE, I added two additional filters:

```
AND c.id <> ca2.customerID 
AND c2.id <> ca.customerID
```

And the dataset looks like I want ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZvYs.png)):

```
+ ---------- + ---------- + --------- + ---------- + -------- + ---------- + --------------------- + ------------ + ----- + ----- + ------------- + --------- + ------------- + ----------- + ------------- + --------------------- + ------------ + -------- + ------ +
| SSNRanking | CustomerID | SSN       | FirstName  | LastName | BirthDate  | Addr1                 | City         | State | Zip   | DupCustomerID | DupSSN    | DupFirstName  | DupLastName | DupBirthDate  | DupAddr1              | DupCity      | DupState | DupZip |
+ ---------- + ---------- + --------- + ---------- + -------- + ---------- + --------------------- + ------------ + ----- + ----- + ------------- + --------- + ------------- + ----------- + ------------- + --------------------- + ------------ + -------- + ------ +
| 1          | 1545229    | 000000000 | Aquia Boat | SALES    | 1900-01-01 | 236 Willow Landing Rd | Stafford     | VA    | 22554 | 2020589       | 000000000 | DIXIE         | SALES       | 1900-01-01    | 236 Willow Landing Rd | Stafford     | VA       | 22554  | 
| 1          | 2020489    | 000000000 | DIXIE      | SALES    | 1900-01-01 | 11963 Jefferson Ave   | Newport News | VA    | 23606 | 1545229       | 000000000 | AQUIA BOAT    | SALES       | 1900-01-01    | 11963 Jefferson Ave   | Newport News | VA       | 23606  | 
+ ---------- + ---------- + --------- + ---------- + -------- + ---------- + --------------------- + ------------ + ----- + ----- + ------------- + --------- + ------------- + ----------- + ------------- + --------------------- + ------------ + -------- + ------ +
```

Can I prevent the CROSS APPLY from creating additional records for customers with mailing address assigned to another customer?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept fiddling with the report and I was able to achieve my desired results by adding another CTE and ROW_NUMBER function to remove the duplicate rows I was seeing.  Seems like overkill for my desired outcome, but this runs much faster than my original query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DupSSN') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #DupSSN;

WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c.socialSecurityNumber) AS [SSNRanking] ,

    c.socialSecurityNumber AS [SSN],
    RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(c.socialSecurityNumber, 1, 3))) + '-' + RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(c.socialSecurityNumber, 4, 2))) + '-' + RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(c.socialSecurityNumber, 6, 4))) AS [F_SSN] ,
    c.id AS [CustomerID] ,
    REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.firstName)), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' ') AS [FirstName] ,
    REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.lastName)), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' ') AS [LastName] ,
    c.birthDate AS [BirthDate] ,
    MAX(co.orderDate) AS [LastOrderDate] ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ca.street1)) AS [Addr1] ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ca.city)) AS [City] ,
    ca.stateAndTerritoriesID AS [State] ,
    ca.zipCode5 AS [Zip] ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(c.emailAddress)) AS [EmailAddress] ,
    c.createDate AS [CreateDate] ,

    c2.socialSecurityNumber AS [DupSSN] ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(C2.socialSecurityNumber, 1, 3))) + '-' + RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(C2.socialSecurityNumber, 4, 2))) + '-' + RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(C2.socialSecurityNumber, 6, 4))) AS [F_DupSSn] ,
    c2.id AS [DupCustomerID] ,
    REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(c2.firstName)), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' ') AS [DupFirstName] ,
    REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(c2.lastName)), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' ') AS [DupLastName] ,
    c2.birthDate AS [DupBirthDate] ,
    MAX(co2.orderDate) AS [DupLastOrderDate] ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ca2.street1)) AS [DupAddr1] ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ca2.city)) AS [DupCity] ,
    ca2.stateAndTerritoriesID AS [DupState] ,
    ca2.zipCode5 AS [DupZip] ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(c2.emailAddress)) AS [DupEmailAddress] ,
    c2.createDate AS [DupCreateDate]

FROM    dbo.Customers AS [c]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customers AS [c2] ON ( SUBSTRING(c.socialSecurityNumber,6,4) = SUBSTRING(c2.socialSecurityNumber,6,4) AND c.birthDate = c2.birthDate AND c.lastName = c2.lastName AND c.id <> c2.id )
    INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerAddresses AS [ca] ON c.id = ca.customerID   
    INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerAddresses AS [ca2] ON c2.id = ca2.customerID         
    INNER JOIN dbo.Common_Orders AS [co] ON co.customerID = c.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.Common_Orders AS [co2] ON co2.customerID = c2.id
WHERE   c.customerStatusTypeID <> 'M'
    AND c2.customerStatusTypeID <> 'M'
    AND ca.addressType <> 'M'
    AND ca2.addressType <> 'M'
    AND c.mergedTo IS NULL
    AND c2.mergedTo IS NULL
    AND CAST(co.orderDate AS DATE) >= '3/1/2017'
    AND CAST(co.orderDate AS DATE) <= '3/31/2017'
GROUP BY c.socialSecurityNumber ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(c.socialSecurityNumber, 1, 3))) + '-' + RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(c.socialSecurityNumber, 4, 2))) + '-' + RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(c.socialSecurityNumber, 6, 4))) ,
    c.id ,
    REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.firstName)), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' ') ,
    REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.lastName)), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' ') ,
    c.birthDate ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(CA.street1)) ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(CA.city)) ,
    CA.stateAndTerritoriesID ,
    CA.zipCode5 ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(c.emailAddress)) ,
    c.createDate ,

    c2.socialSecurityNumber ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(C2.socialSecurityNumber, 1, 3))) + '-' + RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(C2.socialSecurityNumber, 4, 2))) + '-' + RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(C2.socialSecurityNumber, 6, 4))) ,
    c2.id ,
    REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(c2.firstName)), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' ') ,
    REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(c2.lastName)), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' ') ,
    c2.birthDate ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ca2.street1)) ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ca2.city)) ,
    ca2.stateAndTerritoriesID ,
    ca2.zipCode5 ,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(c2.emailAddress)) ,
    c2.createDate
)
-- Use a CTE to cross apply or unpivot the potential duplicates into separate rows
SELECT  ca.SSNRanking ,
    ca.SSN ,
    ca.F_SSN ,
    ca.CustomerID ,
    ca.FirstName ,
    ca.LastName ,
    ca.BirthDate ,
    ca.LastOrderDate ,
    ca.Addr1 ,
    ca.City ,
    ca.[State] ,
    ca.Zip ,
    ca.EmailAddress ,
    ca.CreateDate
INTO    #DupSSN

FROM cte
CROSS APPLY
(
VALUES
( cte.SSNRanking, cte.SSN,    cte.F_SSN, cte.CustomerID,    cte.FirstName,    cte.LastName,    cte.BirthDate,    cte.LastOrderDate,   cte.Addr1,    cte.City,    cte.[State],  cte.Zip,    cte.EmailAddress,    cte.CreateDate ) ,
( cte.SSNRanking, cte.DupSSN, cte.F_SSN, cte.DupCustomerID, cte.DupFirstName, cte.DupLastName, cte.DupBirthDate, cte.DupLastOrderDate,cte.DupAddr1, cte.DupCity, cte.DupState, cte.DupZip, cte.DupEmailAddress, cte.DupCreateDate )
) AS ca (SSNRanking, SSN, F_SSN, CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, LastOrderDate, Addr1, City, State, Zip, EmailAddress, CreateDate)
ORDER BY CAST(ca.SSN AS INT) ASC, ca.CustomerID;

-- Use CTE to create ROW_NUMBER function to eliminate duplicate records
WITH SSN_RN AS
(
SELECT  SSNRanking ,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY SSN, CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, LastOrderDate, Addr1, City, CreateDate ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS [RowNumber] ,
    SSN ,
    F_SSN ,
    CustomerID ,
    FirstName ,
    LastName ,
    BirthDate ,
    LastOrderDate ,
    Addr1 ,
    City ,
    State ,
    Zip ,
    EmailAddress ,
    CreateDate
FROM    #DupSSN
)
SELECT  SSN_RN.SSNRanking ,
    SSN_RN.RowNumber ,
    SSN_RN.SSN ,
    SSN_RN.F_SSN ,
    SSN_RN.CustomerID ,
    SSN_RN.FirstName ,
    SSN_RN.LastName ,
    SSN_RN.BirthDate ,
    SSN_RN.LastOrderDate ,
    SSN_RN.Addr1 ,
    SSN_RN.City ,
    SSN_RN.State ,
    SSN_RN.Zip ,
    SSN_RN.EmailAddress ,
    SSN_RN.CreateDate
FROM    SSN_RN
WHERE   SSN_RN.RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY CAST(SSN_RN.SSN AS INT) ASC ,
    SSN_RN.CustomerID;

DROP TABLE #DupSSN;
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should throw sample data (at least 1 - 20 rows).

Or first you get your query correct then try to find duplicate records.

what do you mean by "the last 4 of an SSN, last name and DOB. " what kind of data you get ?

It appear to be very simple,

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE ( SSN int,lastName varchar(50),DOB datetime)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (50,'Smith','1980-02-02'), 
(50,'Smith1','1980-02-02'),(50,'Smith','1980-02-02'),(50,'Smith','1980-02-02')

;With CTE as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(PARTITION by ssn,lastName,dob order by (select null))rn 
from @SampleData
)
select * from cte
where rn>=4
```